# Camel Use a splitter without aggregator

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and I'd like to use it to read a XML file on a FTP server and to a assynch process for all NODE element of the XML.

Indeed, I'll use a splitter to process every node (I use a stream because the XML file is big).

```
from(ftp://user@host:port/...)
    .split().tokenizeXML("node").streaming()
    .to("seda:processNode")
    .end();
```

Then the route to the nodeProcessor:

```
from("seda:processNode")
    .bean(lookup(MyNodeProcessor.class))
    .end();
```

I was wondering if it's ok to use a splitter without an aggregator? In my case, I don't need to aggregate the outcome of all processed nodes.

I was wondering if it's a problem in Camel to have many "splitted" threads going in a "dead end" instead of being aggreagated?

The examples provided by Camel show a splitter withtout an aggregator, but they still provide an aggregationStrategy with the splitter. Is it mandatory?

Comment: This might be interessting: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/splitter-without-aggregator-td5713574.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is perfect fine, you can use the splitter without the agg strategy which would be normal, like the splitter EIP: http://camel.apache.org/splitter

If you use an agg strategy then its more like this EIP: http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html which can be done with splitter only in Camel.

Comment: The links no longer work. This should be it: [https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html) and [https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/composed-message-processor.html](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/composed-message-processor.html)